# Rotate a sprite in the direction of it's movement vector

Tags: c#, xna, rotation, atan2

I've got an XNA Windows Phone Game and you move a sprite with the accelerometer

My problem is that I can't figure out how to make the sprite face the direction it is moving.
So far this is my code:

```
        arrowPos.Y += -accelState.X*10; 
        arrowPos.X += -accelState.Y*10;

        rotation = -(float)Math.Atan2(arrowPos.Y, arrowPos.X);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current `rotation` calculation uses the current position of the sprite - the sprite may be in that position whether it is moving north or west.

Try using the `accelState.X` and `accelState.Y` values instead.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was such an obvious mistake. I could kick myself for overlooking it